# What i should write in Pro-guard Files to stop reverse engineering android?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am using android studio I have generated release Apk when i use Apk-one-click it gives me complete code I know i have to use Proguard but how i can use???
I building Apk using release but it still readable by reverse engineering.

Comment: Did you read [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) and tried following?

Comment: yes i have check it but don't know how to use??

Comment: see the mapping.txt. You can see what is happening. This may not be a ProGuard Issue. Proguard is for Code Coverage Optimization.

Comment: > While using android studio, [you must add Proguard to your gradle.build file's build types. For more information, see the Gradle Plugin User Guide.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard)

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode. Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended. You can configure Proguard is following situations

- a class that is referenced only in the AndroidManifest.xml file
- a method called from JNI
- dynamically referenced fields and methods

You can fix errors when ProGuard strips away your code by adding a -keep line in the proguard.cfg file.

```
-keep public class <MyClass>
```

Comment: How to use in android studio ??

Comment: Check <project_root>/bin/proguard/mapping.txt for mapping between Original and Obfuscated Class Names.